# Subwoofer Activation

Tags: 12.04, sound

I have a Dell Vostro 5470 with an i5 processor and a built-in subwoofer running on Ubuntu. The subwoofer, however, does not work. Does anyone know how to switch it on or activate it so that I can use it? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

p.s I have the same problem with the built-in fingerprint scanner.